# Some of the files failed to copy during deployment of the solution

Tags: powershell, solution-deployment, sharepoint-farm

I tried to deploy a solution to our server, but it seems that there are two WFE servers (I am not sure about this if they are both WFE or WFE and application server. How can I see the difference?).

After it has been installed, it throws the following error:

```
SPS01 : http://interact-prod.local/ : The solution was successfully deployed. 
SPS02 : http://interact-prod.local/ : InterAct : Error: Cannot locate the <SafeControls> section in the web.config file for this site. Controls in the specified assembly cannot be marked as <SafeControls>.
```

What could be the reason that I cannot copy the files in the second server?
Do I need to modify something in the Solution itself?

I compared both web.configs from both servers, but they are not the same.
SafeControls and sectionGroup are both missing in the second server, SPS02.

Another thing I noticed, perhaps this is not that important, is that the name of the folder in wwwroot for both sites is a bit different:

```
Server 1 : interact-prod.local80
Server 2 : Interact-prod.local80
```

One has a capital "I", the otherone is in lowercase. Perhaps this is not important but I am just mentioning it. Perhaps the sites are not the same after all.

The site is not in use yet, but if I delete the web application and the content database, will it remove it on the other server, or shall I do that manually?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As you already compare the web.config files and found the gap between them.  So now you have couple of options to fix it.

1. copy the web.config from server 1 to server 2.
2. 2nd is edit the web.config on server 2 and add the safecontrol section

You also mentioned, it is brand new web application not being used, then i would recommend to delete the existing web app with database. When you delete it from central admin, it ask you **remove from IIS** and **remove the database**. You should select both, this way it will delete the web app from both servers.

But you have issues in farm, i would check the both server after the deletion and make sure no IIS site exist.